# How could I insert several rows values from a datagridview into a single field of a table?

Tags: c#, datagridview, insert, field, rows

I got a form where I make a list of articles the client want to buy and I need to save all the articles names into a single field something like: `article 1, article 2, article 3` so when I print the report I can see all the articles in a single row but I really dont know how to do it I tried a couple of ways but the only thing I could do was count the ammount of rows, by the way Im inserting the values in the other fields using parameters so I cant make it changing the query, this is what I'm using:

```
private void btnfacturar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var articulos = new List<string>(); 
    var combinedString = string.Empty;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) 
    { 
       string strArticulos = row.Cells["Articulos"].Value.ToString();
       articulos.Add(strArticulos); //this should make it easier for you to understand
    }
    combinedString = string.Join<string>(" ", articulos);

   try
   {
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=dbpuntodeventa;Integrated Security=True");
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO equipos VALUES (@nombre,@estado,@servicio,@fechaderecepcion,@nombredecliente, @apellido, @edad, @documento,@tipodedocumento,@email,@telefono,@direccion,@imagen,@piezas,@tipodepago,@abono,@garante,@preciodepiezas,@manodeobra,@total,@devuelta,@descuento,@imagendedocumento,@pago,@itbis,@tamaño,@capacidad,@marca,@modelo)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nombre", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@estado", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@servicio", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fechaderecepcion", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nombredecliente", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@apellido", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@edad", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@documento", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 13);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tipodedocumento", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 35);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@telefono", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 12);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@direccion", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagen", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@piezas", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tipodepago", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@abono", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@garante", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@preciodepiezas", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@manodeobra", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@total", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@devuelta", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@descuento", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagendedocumento", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pago", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@itbis", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tamaño", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@capacidad", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@marca", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@modelo", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);


    cmd.Parameters["@nombre"].Value = equipoTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@estado"].Value = estadoTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@servicio"].Value = servicioComboBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@fechaderecepcion"].Value = txtfecha.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@nombredecliente"].Value = nombreTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@apellido"].Value = apellidoTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@edad"].Value = edadTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@documento"].Value = documentoMaskedTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@tipodedocumento"].Value = tipodedocumentoComboBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@email"].Value = emailTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@telefono"].Value = telefonoMaskedTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@direccion"].Value = direccionTextBox.Text;
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    imagenPictureBox.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    cmd.Parameters["@imagen"].Value = ms.GetBuffer();
    cmd.Parameters["@piezas"].Value = articulos;
    cmd.Parameters["@tipodepago"].Value = cbtipodepago.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@abono"].Value = txtabono.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@garante"].Value = txtgarante.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@preciodepiezas"].Value = txtpreciodepiezas.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@manodeobra"].Value = txtmanodeobra.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@total"].Value = txttotal.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@devuelta"].Value = txtsobrante.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@descuento"].Value = cbdescuento.Text;
    System.IO.MemoryStream msi = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    imagendedocumentoPictureBox.Image.Save(msi, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    cmd.Parameters["@imagendedocumento"].Value = msi.GetBuffer();
    cmd.Parameters["@pago"].Value = txtpago.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@itbis"].Value = txtitbis.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@tamaño"].Value = tamañoTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@capacidad"].Value = capacidadTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@marca"].Value = marcaTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@modelo"].Value = modeloTextBox.Text;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Exito");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

    }
    if (txtgarante.Text == "")
    {
                frmfactura frma = new frmfactura();
                frma.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
      frmrecibo frm = new frmrecibo();
      frm.ShowDialog();
      frmfactura2 frmi = new frmfactura2();
      frmi.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show what code you have as well as a valid representation of what you have and what your expected outcome is.. it's not difficult to save all the values from each row and then insert them into a database field.. are you familiar with `string.Join()` you could add all the values to a `List<T> of String` for example `var articleList = new List<string>()` then for each for add the items to a list..then before updating implement `string.Join()` method on the List<T> to save as a single string value

Comment: something like this var articulos = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                articulos = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Precio"].Value);
                } ?

Comment: can you paste the example in your original question please..?

Comment: also you need to read up on `Collection Objects` they all have an `Add()` method so to add the items in a foreach loop you would need `articulos.Add(` then what ever values you want to add.. you could also concat the values by adding with a `,` separator and then when you implement the join you could join on the `,` and use inline `.Replace(",", " ")` but lets take this one step at a time

Comment: ok I got the add part now I have something like this: 

var articulos = new List<string>(); 
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) 
            { 
                articulos.Add(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Precio"].Value)); 
            }

and I'm not getting any sintax error but Im not getting the "," part

Comment: when you are done looping thru the code what are the values of the `articulos` List..?

Comment: if the List<string> is fully populated then create a method or assign a `variable` for example 
`string combinedString = string.Join<string>(" ", articulos);`

Comment: now I'm getting this error at the executenonquery part Failed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a String.

Comment: I can't see what you are seeing you need to post all the code that relates to your issue.. also update your code using the original question to place any new code..

Comment: you need to pass a string variable to the stored procedure.. show me the code for the Insert method..

Comment: ok I posted the whole code now I didnt do it since the beginning cause is too long

Comment: are you familiar with scope of variables.. look at my answer for updated declaration of the string variable..

Comment: you do not need to put the join() function inside the loop do it after the loop has completed..

Comment: I see so many other potential problems / issues you are going to run into.. for example this line ` System.IO.MemoryStream msi = new System.IO.MemoryStream();` If I were you after successful execution of the ExecutNonQuery call I would do something like `((IDisposable)msi).Dispose()` lots of potential memory leaks in your code

Comment: the name is piezas and I have a question is the second part of the code mandatory to use or is it optional? cause Im already getting an error on the string.empty part

Comment: look at my answer I need you to step thru the code using the debugger too.. I want to know what the values of `articulos` after the loop..

Comment: I know but I cant do it cause Im getting that string.empty error

Comment: how are you getting a string.Empty() error can you elaborate or show me ..because I am not following you.. you have to change it to      `var combinedString = string.Empty;` sorry about that..

Comment: in the empty part says non-invocable member 'string.empty' cannot be used like a method

Comment: I will fix it.. you are not seeing the difference ? I will fix it in your existing code ..

Comment: I am still a bit suspect about the Image code that you are using.. but I will wait until you get to that point I am taking off look at your original code in your question I updated what you need to get the string.Empty; to work.. also I would consider converting the SQL code into a separate Method 
I wonder if this will work in your code or not `System.IO.MemoryStream msi = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    imagendedocumentoPictureBox.Image.Save(msi, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    cmd.Parameters["@imagendedocumento"].Value = msi.GetBuffer();` it looks suspect but I can't tell

Comment: now I got no sintax error but when I press the button I get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in this line string strArticulos = row.Cells["Articulo"].Value.ToString();

Comment: I think that you need to debug this .. I can not do this for you if I had the full project may be a different story.. `dataGridView1.Rows` is that datagrid populated.. you need to step thru this line by line to make sure you are not overriding and of the objects.. I have to go.. do a google search on the exact thing `C# foreach (DataGridViewRow row in` copy and past that in google and you will find lots of examples have a good weekend

Comment: Im debuging it but anyways thanks for the help

Comment: I will check on your progress over the weekend..

Comment: I already solved it just had to change  row.Cells["Articulos"].Value.ToString(); for  Convert.toString(row.Cells["Articulos"].Value);
thanks again for helping me have a good weekend

Comment: sounds good you could also use the string casting as well if you are not aware of `(string)row.Cells["Articulos"].Value;` || 
`(string)row.Cells["Articulos"].Value.ToString();` when ever you have an object for example rows or if you were doing something using `ActiveDirectory` for example you need to cast the object type or use the Convert.To method.. glad I could help and I commend you on not giving up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this code works then do the following after to store the strings in the list into a single `string` variable

```
var articulos = new List<string>(); 
var combinedString = string.Empty;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) 
{ 
   string strArticulos = row.Cells["Articulos"].Value.ToString();
   articulos.Add(strArticulos); //this should make it easier for you to understand
}
combinedString = string.Join<string>(" ", articulos);
```

> this will have all the articles separated by a " " like article1 artice2 article3 
>       string combinedString = string.Join(" ", articulos);

I would experiment with this portion `string.Join<string>(" "` and try other delimiters such as `*, , #` but becareful when using special characters when trying to insert into SQL Server it's seen as `Injection` and I would stick to using `,` comma delimiters or spaces " " for example

if you want to call the above as a Method then here is the following

```
var combinedStr = InsertConcatValuesIntoDB(articulos);

private static stringInsertConcatValuesIntoDB(List<string> aList)
{
    string combinedString = string.Join<string>(" ", aList);
    return combinedString;
}
```

> this line cmd.Parameters["@piezas"].Value = articulos;` should be this

```
cmd.Parameters["@piezas"].Value = combinedStr;
```